# Dirty form - how to ignore dirty form pop up on parent.window.location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-dirtyforms

```
$('#js_eligibilty_discard').on('click',
    function(e) {
        $.DirtyForms.choiceContinue = true;

        $("#test").dialog('close');
        $("#js-ErrorPopup").dialog('close');

        $('body').dialogPartialLoader('Processing');

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: GlobalVars['app_url'] + "/web/xyz/cancel?xyz=${param.xyz}",

                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    parent.window.location.href = GlobalVars["app_url"] + "/individual/findPlans"

                },
                error: function(data) {
                    $('body').dialogClose();
                    alert(data.statusText);
                }
            });

        return false;

        $.DirtyForms.choiceCommit(e);
    });
```

I am getting default pop up of dirty form.

Answer (score 1):

Dirty Forms 1.x watches the top document (when hosted within a frame) by default. You can disable this functionality by calling ignoreParentDocs() (which is incorrectly named, it should be `ignoreTopDocument()` to reflect what it actually does).

```
$.DirtyForms.ignoreParentDocs();
```

Dirty Forms 2.x no longer watches the top document by default, but you can [customize event binding](https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms#event-handler-customization) to change which frames are watched and which target frame to redirect if the user decides to proceed.

Also, `$.DirtyForms.choiceContinue` and `$.DirtyForms.choiceCommit()` can only be called from within a dialog module (after `fire()` is called) for them to have any effect, but it is unclear from your question if that is what you are doing.